# How to add -std=c++17 to my mingw32-make?

Tags: c++, makefile, emacs, c++17, tdm-gcc

I have started to use Emacs for c++ programming. For the compiler, I downloaded TDM-GCC-64. But when I type `M-x compile` it would ask for `make -k` and after that it would throw an error of not recognizing `make`. So I then downloaded `mingw32-make`. And everything worked but I want to use C++17 and it does not support that, so I read about editing `makefile` but I couldn't find one: the only thing there is is `make.exe`. What should I do now?

Comment: _" I want to use C++17 and it does not support that"_ how do you know? What have you tried? Specifically: what does `g++ --version` give and whet if you try with `g++ -std=c++1z`?

Comment: I wrote        vector<pair<ll,ll>> v;       v.push_back({a,b})      instead of  make_pair which ofcourse is supported by c++11 & c++17 .So it threw the error . My g++ --version is 5.1.0  . And I actually want to add -std=c++17 but when I type M-x compile it starts make -k  and after I enter the name of output file , it directly starts the command g++ A.cpp -o  without giving me chance to add this thing -std=c++17. So basically where should I add this?

Comment: either set `compile-command` or type `C-u M-x compile` and enter the compile command manually

Comment: Yep it worked now . Thanks to all :)